# Is there a way to detect text overflow when using OutlinedTextField in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to reduce the font size if the text overflows, but there is no onTextLayout in OutlinedTextField, because the value parameter uses TextFieldValue or String instead of Text.
Is there another way to achieve this?